# Possible to publish OneNote content to the web?

Tags: ms-office, office365, onenote

I have a notebook full of content I am looking to publish online, but the problem I am running into is I can't find a method that will retain the original formatting. I understand I might have to recreate the navigational tabs/pages, but I trying to avoid having to recreate the content in a different format.

Is there anyway to export a form of the content that maintains the tables, text formatting and etc.?

Answer (score 1):

Why not get a read only sharing link to your notebook?

I think the closest thing to what you want is this:
https://thenextweb.com/apps/2015/05/22/microsofts-new-wordpress-plugin-lets-you-directly-publish-your-onenote-documents/#.tnw_o7KuyR9D